# I call a javascript function for print but doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I use below code for print from Page but doesn't work (means when i click on print button nothing happen). the function doesn't call

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function printing() {
            window.print();
        }
    </script>

protected void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return printing()");
}
```

Comment: Did you check javascript console for errors. Also try putting a `console.log` call to the `printing()` function to see if it's called

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
<asp:Button ID="print" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `attribute` in page_load event to `bind` the javascript `event`, so that the javascript is binded before you click the print button to print the page.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    btnPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return printing()");
    //Your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks the button, you are adding an attribute, not calling the `printing()` function.

You should add the `OnClientClick` attribute to the button in the button html like this:

`<asp:button OnClientClick="return printing" ....`